# ESLint sort imports multiline wrap

Tags: javascript, eslint, prettier

I'd like to use the **sort-imports** eslint rule for sorting imports statements, but when I hace a multiline import it breaks every imported thing into a new line.

My problem is that I want to make imports multiline, but wrapping after an specified width.

```js
//My use case
import { a, b, c, z, x, h } from x;

//How is linting
import {
  a
  , b
  , c
  , h
  , x
  , z
} from x;

//How I want to works
import {
  a, b, c
  , h, x, z
} from x;
```

In this case with just 3 imports I dont mind if the imported things are just in one line, but my problem is when i have a lot of thing (like if I'm importing 20 ramda functions) and I dont want to break every imported function into a new line.

This is my currently eslint + prettier config:

.eslintrc.json

```
{
  "root": true,
  "extends": [
    "plugin:vue/essential",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "eslint:recommended"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2019,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "env": {
    "es6": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "indent": ["error", 2],
    "arrow-parens": ["error", "always"],
    "sort-imports": [
      "error",
      {
        "ignoreDeclarationSort": true
      }
    ],
    "comma-style": ["error", "first"],
    "comma-spacing" :["error", {
      "after": true
    }]
  }
}
```

.prettierrc.json

```
{
  "arrowParens": "always",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "css",
  "insertPragma": false,
  "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
  "jsxSingleQuote": false,
  "printWidth": 80,
  "proseWrap": "preserve",
  "quoteProps": "as-needed",
  "requirePragma": true,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "useTabs": false,
  "vueIndentScriptAndStyle": false
}
```

Comment: As a general idea you should have only one import per line so that you can easily track changes in your versioning system (ie Git).

Comment: its easily to track changes even if they are in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

You should load `plugin:prettier/recommended` after `eslint:recommended` to stop eslint reformatting stuff that prettier takes care off